# How to I configure Eclipse PDT 2.1 to display PHP CLI output in the console?

Tags: eclipse, stdout, php-cli, stderr

Starting with a recent version of Eclipse PDT, the standard out and standard error from executed PHP CLI code doesn't appear in the console anymore. (It still shows up in the Debug-perspective in the Debug Output-view).

How can I change this back so that PHP CLI output arrives in the console again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for the bug to get fixed. :(
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282997

If you find another solution, let me know please!

Comment: Sigh, nothing so far, except for the output showing up in the Debug console.

Comment: This issue is a real bugbear for me, as it makes PDT 2.1 practically unusable.

Comment: According to the bug report, this is fixed in PDT 3.0.